# Find sign( $+, -$) of the following $P(x) = (2-3x)(x^2-x-2)(x^2-x+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not asking to solve the exercise but to show me the logic you use to solve it(I need to know how this type of exercise is solved). The exercise says: "Find the sign $ (+\ or\ -)$ of the following representation"

$P(x) = (2-3x)(x^2-x-2)(x^2-x+1)$

Sorry if there are terminology errors of mine. English is my second language

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of the sign? (Perhaps you can edit this in your question).

Comment: @Student The execrise needs to find if the above is positive or negative for the different values of x

Comment: Note that your polynomial is factored into other polynomials, so it suffices to check for these polynomials where it is positive/negative. For example: $2 - 3x$ is positive if $x \leq \frac{2}{3}$, so we find that $2 - 3x$ is positive on the interval $[\frac{2}{3}, +\infty[$ and negative elsewhere. Do this for all three polynomials and then use that a positive number times a negative number is negative etc.

Comment: @Student Ok I get it. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if things worked out or not. If not, I can write you an answer.

Comment: @Student The representation is positive when x belongs to (-∞, -1) and (2/3,2). Negative when x belongs to (-1, 2/3) and (2, +∞). The representation is 0 when x = -1, 2/3 and 2. Did you find the same results?

Comment: Plotting this function in GeoGebra says you are right :)

Comment: @Student how did you put the problem into that app?

Comment: I just used the input ' (2 - 3x) (x² - x - 2) (x² - x + 1) ' which works just fine.